# Is my rim cracked, or is it something else?

Tags: rims, crack, canyon

I had my canyon torque AL5 29inch for 12 days.  Today I saw this on my rim.

Is it a crack, or is it something else?

The crack is positioned at the opposite site of the valve.

[image]

Comment: That's the seam that joins the two ends of the strip that was formed into a circle.

Comment: If you still have doubts, then contact the shop who sold you the bike for confirmation.

Comment: Actually, this looks more like a crack than the rim seam. I am focusing on the jagged edge and the fact that it doesn’t go all the way through. I have edited my answer to the question that was tagg3 as duplicated, and I linked this photo.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I think the jagged edge is the decals tearing.  I think in this case the best way to tell would be to take the tyre off and inspect from the inside.