# I have a double walled bicycle wheel frame seam that has a gap underneath NOT on top? It does not go all the way round, only underneath. Is this fine?

Tags: road-bike

I have a double walled bicycle wheel frame seam that has a gap underneath NOT on top? It does not go all the way round, only underneath. Is this fine?

The bicycle is a No Logo X-type racing alloy bike with alloy rim wheels. The rim seam gap is on both front and rear wheels and isn't no wider than the thickness of a bank card.

the split on both wheels doesn't extend beyond where the rim brakes hit the wheel to stop the bike moving.

is their any concern for safety problems or is it a natural manufacture making of the tyres?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to describe.  Most metal bike rims have a seam where the two ends of the semi-circular metal hoop are joined together to make a solid circle.  How this is done is one of the details that can make a rim reliable or not so reliable.

Comment: Please read https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77050/crack-on-bike-wheel-rim and see if this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: A picture would help us understand